# Attach conditions to eventTarget

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

this is my first question here. It's probably really simple, but I'm having some issues with eventListeners and event.target. So here is the html and my JS, and what i want to do is, when i click on a IMG element, I want to know if its either in the 'player1Div' or the 'player2Div'. I was able to create an eventListener for the whole 'section', and have him trigger when I click on a e.target.tagName = 'IMG', however I dont know how to distinguish between player1Div & player2Div

Here is the HTML

```
<section class="cards">
    <div id="player1Div">
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="2" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="15" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="4" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="12" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="6" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="10" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="8" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="9" />
    </div>
    <div id="result">
        <span></span>
        <span>vs</span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div id="player2Div">
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="10" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="14" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="9" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="7" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="11" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="5" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="13" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="3" />
    </div>
```

Here is the JS for the eventlistener:

```
    section.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
        //add to an array of either player1 results or player2 results, depending on the 'click'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're adding the event listeners to the divs by their ID, that section of your code already knows which ID you're looking at. So you can just reference that; for instance:

```
document.getElementById('player1Div').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
    // You're in player1Div!
  }
});
document.getElementById('player2Div').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
    // You're in player2Div!
  }
});
```

Alternatively, if you need to add the click handler onto the whole section, you can use the target's `parentNode` property to get the DIV and then access its id:

```
const section = document.querySelector('section.cards');
section.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
    const parentID = e.target.parentNode.id;
    // Do what you want based on the parentID!
  }
});
```

The only issue with this latter approach is if you change the structure of your DIVs -- like putting another inner container around the images -- it will break, while the first approach won't. You'll end up needing to change how you traverse the DOM, i.e. adding more or less `parentNodes`, maybe some `nextSiblings` as well. That's why I recommend the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parentNode` to get the parent and from there get the ID. Then you can add to whichever array you want based on that.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  const section = document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0]
  const player1 = []
  const player2 = []

  section.addEventListener('click', e => {
      if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
          const parentDiv = e.target.parentNode.attributes.id.value
           
          // there are better ways to do this but let's keep it simple
          if (parentDiv === 'player1Div') {
            player1.push(e.target)
          } else {
            player2.push(e.target)
          }
      }
      
      const result = document.getElementById('result')
      const player1Result = result.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]
      const player2Result = result.getElementsByTagName('span')[2]
      
      player1Result.innerText = player1.length
      player2Result.innerText = player2.length
  })
  
 })
```

```html
<section class="cards">
    <div id="player1Div">
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="2" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="15" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="4" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="12" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="6" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="10" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="8" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="9" />
    </div>
    <div id="result">
        <span></span>
        <span>vs</span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div id="player2Div">
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="10" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="14" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="9" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="7" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="11" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="5" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="13" />
        <img src="images/card.jpg" name="3" />
    </div>
</section>
```